# How do I statically link a Haskell library with a Rust project?

Tags: haskell, rust, ffi

I’ve had no luck so far with linking a Haskell library to a Rust project. I’ve had a lot of errors, the latest being the `recompile with -fPIC` for `ghc`.

I’ve managed to get a functional example of dynamically linking — but have been unable to get it linked statically.

Attaching my current setup right now:

1. build.rs

   ```rust
   fn main() {
       println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=deps");
       println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=tesths");
   }
   ```
2. src/main.rs

   ```rust
   extern "C" {
       pub fn addTwo(x: i32) -> i32;
       pub fn init();
       pub fn fin();
   }

   fn main() {
       println!("Hello, world!");
   }
   ```
3. src/haskell/Lib.hs

   ```hs
   module Lib where

   import Foreign.C.Types

   addTwo :: CInt -> CInt
   addTwo = (2 + )

   foreign export ccall addTwo :: CInt -> CInt
   ```
4. cwrapper.c

   ```c
   #include <HsFFI.h>
   #ifdef __GLASGOW_HASKELL__
   #include "Lib_stub.h"
   #endif
   #include <stdio.h>

   void init(void) {
     static char *argv[] = {"libhs.so", 0}, **argv_ = argv;
     static int argc = 1;

     hs_init(&argc, &argv_);
   }

   void fin(void) { hs_exit(); }
   ```

I compile #4 with `ghc -c -static -lHSrts -lffi cwrapper.c`, getting `cwrapper.o`. Similarly, I compile #3 with `ghc -c -static -fPIC -lffi Lib.hs` and get object code for that as well.

Once that is done, I go ahead and archive the two with `ar rcs libtesths.a Lib.o cwrapper.o`.

On `cargo build`:

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: deps/libtesths.a(Lib.o):(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `newCAF'
          /usr/bin/ld: deps/libtesths.a(Lib.o):(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `stg_bh_upd_frame_info'
          /usr/bin/ld: deps/libtesths.a(Lib.o):(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `base_ForeignziCziTypes_zdfNumCInt_closure'
          /usr/bin/ld: deps/libtesths.a(Lib.o):(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `stg_ap_p_info'
…
```

I’ve got a hunch that libHSrts isn’t being linked statically for some reason.

### Update

I followed Shepmaster’s advice and successfully made a working example. But I’m having issues linking with my rust exec now.

I used stack with `ghc-options: -staticlib -stubdir .` and `c-sources: cwrapper.c` to build. When I try to build the rust project with `cargo rustc — -C relocation-model=static`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: deps/liba.a(Type.o): in function `integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwplusBigNatWord_info'
(.text.integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwplusBigNatWord_info+0x128): undefined reference to `__gmpn_add_1'
/usr/bin/ld: deps/liba.a(Type.o): in function
`integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwminusBigNatWord_info'
(.text.integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwminusBigNatWord_info+0xdf): undefined reference to `__gmpn_sub_1'
/usr/bin/ld: deps/liba.a(Type.o): in function `integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_complementInteger_info'
(.text.integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_complementInteger_info+0x138): undefined reference to `__gmpn_sub_1'
/usr/bin/ld: deps/liba.a(Type.o): in function `integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwtimesBigNatWord_info'
(.text.integerzmwiredzmin_GHCziIntegerziType_zdwtimesBigNatWord_info+0x158): undefined reference to `__gmpn_mul_1'
```

There is also mention of a `wrappers.o`. Any help is appreciated.

### Update 2

I solved the `gmp` issues by setting `build.rs` to link `libgmp` as well. I have a different problem now, though.

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: deps/libhssource.a(Lib.o): in function `testFFI':
          (.text+0x88fd): multiple definition of `testFFI'; deps/libhssource.a(Lib.o):(.text+0x1b66): first defined here
          /usr/bin/ld: deps/libhssource.a(cwrapper.o): in function `init':
          cwrapper.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `init'; deps/libhssource.a(cwrapper.o):cwrapper.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
          /usr/bin/ld: deps/libhssource.a(cwrapper.o): in function `fin':
          cwrapper.c:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `fin'; deps/libhssource.a(cwrapper.o):cwrapper.c:(.text+0x1a): first defined here
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### Update 3

This the final build command that does the trick:

```
cargo rustc -- -C relocation-model=static -Clink-arg=-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
```

Using `RUSTFLAGS` will cause the build to crash because it builds all the dependencies with a static relocation model, which won’t work — in my case — for the `rustversion` crate. It will report a `recompile with -fPIC` error.

Comment: Wow, @Shepmaster, I was just googling around and I saw your FFI omnibus repo! Stellar stuff! It’s a pity I’m trying to do it the other way around :(

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. The good news is that a large proportion of the knowledge is transferable (not for this case, though).

Comment: Both SmokedTurkey and @shepmaster: I wanna know what immensely cool projects you're working on that involve FFI-ing between the world's two best languages!

Comment: @gspr Haha.. I’m working on some analytics software. Haskell is a beast and perfect for when you want some concise but zippy code that describes really involved algorithms in a handful of lines. I was shell-shocked when I first found out how unbelievably good GHC is as a compiler. `rustc` and `ghc` are two fine works of art.

Comment: Please don't put _answers_ in the _question_. You can add you own answer and even accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I compiled the Haskell library and C shim at once, passing the [`-staticlib`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.7/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#ghc-flag--staticlib) flag:

```
ghc -c -staticlib Lib.hs cwrapper.c -o libtesths.a
```

I then called the functions:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn addTwo(x: i32) -> i32;
    pub fn init();
    pub fn fin();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        init();
        println!("{}", addTwo(40));
        fin();
    }
}
```

```
% cargo run -q
42
```

This worked for me on macOS 12.0.1 on an Apple Silicon processor using GHC 8.10.7.

If you are on x86_64 Linux, you may need to add `RUSTFLAGS='-C relocation-model=static'`.

Comment: I’ve got a different error, now. `… /usr/bin/ld: deps/libtesths.a(Apply.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against \`.rodata.str' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE…`. I attempted to recompile with `-fPIE` and it seemed to compile — but I get the same issue.

Comment: Additionally, I tried `RUSTFLAGS=‘-C relocation-model=pic’ cargo build` as well.

Comment: Figured it out. The solution is to `RUSTFLAGS=‘-C relocation-model=static’ cargo build `

Comment: Thanks! I’ve been tearing my hair out over this!

Comment: Hey, do you happen to know how I can issue the same ghc command for a stack project? Thanks. Merely setting ghc-options and a c-source seems to result in undefined references.

Comment: I’ve been trying to use the FFI for an actual project. But when building with cargo — I get a linker error that has something to do with __gmp* dependencies and `Type.o` and `wrappers.o` — which, if I’m not mistaken, is from the `text` package.

Comment: Have posted an update with the details